# Doesn't recognized my css, js, and so on

Tags: css, .htaccess, styles, mod-rewrite, wamp

I have .htacces like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^en/$             index.php?page=index&lang_id=2
RewriteRule ^contact.html$    index.php?page=contact
RewriteRule ^en/contact.html$ index.php?page=contact&lang_id=2
# ...[and so on]
```

In my site i have a switch language button(image). My basic language is in Ro and and i want to swtich it into En. So, the point is that on a real server, the switcher works. On my local server, wamp, when I try to switch the language, in my browser it appears the text translated (as they are stocked in my database), but it doesn't recognized the css styles, images,...it appears only the text.

Where is the problem ? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using absolute or relative URLs for your external resources?
The problem is probably that the extra folder pre-pended is breaking your relative urls.

So say you are using an image called `logo.png` and is hosted in an images folder, and is referred to with the image tag: `<img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" />`. So normally, if you were on the `contact.html` page, the browser would check the location `http://localhost/images/logo.png` but with your `/en` folder, the browser will check `http://localhost/en/logo.png` which doesn't exist.

The way to fix this is using absolute urls, so using

```
<img src="http://localhost/images/logo.png" alt="logo" />
```

Should fix your issues.

Comment: I have named my folders, images, css, with $BASE_URL just like in this example: "<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{$BASE_URL}css/style.css">" and "<img src="{$BASE_URL}images/header.jpg" style="display: block">" and so on. BASE URL is defined to be the folder in wich i have all my site folders, subfolders etc. BASE URL is defined with Smarty, so can't figured why it doesn't work.

Comment: It looks like you need to set `BASE_URL` yourself, try setting it to `http://localhost/`  otherwise it will simply output relative links again.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you've some rule like `RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1`.

For debugging, use the [HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6647/) extension for Firefox, and look which file is returned by the server, and if it's a `200 OK` response.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser propably makes a request for en/style.css, this gets redirected by the first rule to index.php?page=index&lang_id=2 in other words, it can never find the css that way.

Add

```
RewriteRule (css|jpg|png|gif|js|swf)$ - [L]
```

right after `RewriteEngine On`.

This makes sure that if the extention is one of the above, it doesnt redirect.

**EDIT**

alright say your relative link says css/style.css
this gets automatically converted to baseURL + link
since baseURL will be http://www.example.com/en/ it will look for the css in the folder en/css/style.css instead of css/style.css

one workaround would be to always get your css from your style folder, your images from your images folder, your javascript from your javascript folder etc.

example:

```
RewriteCond ([^/]+css)$ style/$1 [L]
RewriteCond ([^/]+(jpg|png|gif))$ images/$1 [L]
RewriteCond ([^/]+(js))$ javascript/$1 [L]
etc.
```

Comment: my style.css is in a folderd named css/style.css , I put youre code line in my htaccs  but nothing happened. I think is a wamp problem, because as I already said, in my `virtual server` it doesn't work, on a real server it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem I just figured out this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([style|css|js|javascript|images|img|fonts|swf]+)/(.+)\.([^.]+)$ public/$2/$3.$4 [L]
```

as long as all the files are in the directory or sub directory of: style, css, js, javascript, images, img, fonts or swf it will work

change public to what ever folder inside the root, $2 is a folder css, js ... etc $3 is the rest fo the path